# Парсинг корректного числа с сайта

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, lxml

1.Пишу парсер, не могу понять почему при печати словаря из переменной 'price' на экран выводит некорректный текст, когда при печати 'price' отдельно, выводит цену корректно?

2.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Что нужно использовать чтобы убрать пробелы в цене и отсечь денежный знак?
Пробовал отсечь с помощью:

```
for pric in price:
     print(str(pric).replace(' ', ''))
```

- печатает цену столбиком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неразрывные пробелы `0xa0` как и обычные пробелы можно удалить из строки таким образом:

```
s = '123\xa0456'
print(''.join(map(str.strip, s)))
# 123456
```

Вам нужно очистить `price` таким образом. Символ рубля можете перед этим заменить на пустой символ через `.replace`.

Comment: Какой тег выбрать чтобы спарсить только цифры артикула? Все варианты перебрал, ничего не выходит.       <div class="same-part-kt__common-info">
        <p class="same-part-kt__article">
            <span class="hide-mobile">Артикул:</span>
            <span class="hide-desktop">Арт:</span>
            <span data-link="text{: selectedNomenclature^cod1S}">9512622</span>
        </p>

Answer (score 0):

Вот это вот

```
for pric in price:
     print(str(pric).replace(' ', ''))
```

делает следующее: берет по одному символу из строки price и печатает этот символ на новой строчке. Или просто новую строку, если символ был абзац. Кстати, `str()` тут совсем не требуется, потому что `pric` и так уже строка.

Нужно просто удалить пробелы в самой исходной строке:

```
p = price.replace(" ","")
print(p)
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!